# How to create a box where I can add text using JavaScript for my calculator project?

Tags: javascript, html, css

how to create a box where I can add text using JavaScript? I'm currently doing a calculator with CSS, HTML and JavaScript. The thing is that I don't know how to create a box where I can add text with JavaScript. Would a Input or a regular div be better?

Comment: `input` or `textarea`.

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty straight forward:

## The box

#### The easiest way you could use a normal Paragraph (<p>) and give it a border with css.

HTML:

```
<p class="box">Text goes here</p>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

#### Or you could wrap the text in a div to center it there:

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <p class="text">Content</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
     width: 300px;
     height: 100px;  
     display: table; 
     border: 1px solid black;
}

.text {
     text-align: center; 
     vertical-align: middle;
     display: table-cell;   
}
```

With this your text is vertically and horizontally centered inside the div. The dimensions are adjustable with width and height in .box

For docu about the border property check out this page: [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)

## Changing the text with javascript

With document.getElementById() you can get the element itself and then you can set the text with innerHTML like so:

First give you Element a ID:

```
<div class="box">
    <p class="text" id="calculatorOutput">Content</p>
</div>
```

Then in javascript manipulate the value:

```
let calculationResult = 500 * 10; // Example calculation
document.getElementById("calculatorOutput").innerHTML = calculationResult;
```

But over all there dozens of ways to approach this. It depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btns");
let text = document.getElementById("textArea");


buttons.forEach((button)=>{
    button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    text.innerHTML += button.innerText;
  });
});
```

```css
#textArea {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  resize: none;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.container, .btn-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
}

.container {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <textarea id="textArea"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="btn-container">
  <button class="btns">1</button>
  <button class="btns">2</button>
  <button class="btns">3</button>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5z7c30wg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
}

.button{
    width:50px;
    height: 50px; 
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.textview{
    width: 200px; 
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 5px; 
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <form name="form">
            <input class="textview" name="textview">
            <table>
               <tr>
                   <td><input class="button" type="button" value="C"></td>
                   <td><input class="button" type="button" value="<"></td>
                   <td><input class="button" type="button" value="/"></td>
                   <td><input class="button" type="button" value="x"></td>
               </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="7"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="8"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="9"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="-"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="4"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="5"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="6"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="+"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="1" onclick="insert(1)"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="2"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="3"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="="></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```